# Create a url file with multiple links

Tags: linux, text, url

i need to edit the page number of multiple url links in the text file.
eg:

http://gk4success.com/questions.php?page=**1**&parent=0&lang=2&c-id=27&q_type=
...
http://gk4success.com/questions.php?page=**162**&parent=0&lang=2&c-id=27&q_type=

There are 162 links in the web site and i cannot edit links 162 times,even if i copy the lines 162 times,then how do i edit the page numbers easily ? is there any easy way with any text editor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the list

in pure shell:

```
for i in {1..162} ; do echo "http://gk4success.com/questions.php?page=$i&parent=0&lang=2&c-id=27&q_type=" ; done
```

in `vim`:

```
for i in range(1,162)| put ='http://gk4success.com/questions.php?page='.i.'parent=0lang=2c-id=27q_type=' | endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/page=1\&/page=162\&' /path/to/lotsofurls.txt > /path/to/fixedurls.txt
```